# How to stop a function if another function is called in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I've been trying to find out how to stop a function if another function is called or executed in javascript, I am starting to think that it is not possible, hopefully you can change my mind.

Specifically I am working with a timer in a callback function:

```
    function endMatch(){
      // Calculate points
        $("#points").val(touchs*100+seconds*500);
        $("#seconds").val(seconds);
        //stop timer
        // or all ships sunk)
        clearInterval(seconds);

        // Show Dialog to save points
        $.afui.clearHistory();
        $.afui.loadContent("#form",false,false,"up");
        //disable board
}
```

And this is the function that I want to stop so that the user cannot keep playing after the match is over:

```
function shoot(celd, i, j){
  switch (board[i][j]) {
    case 'a':
           board[i][j]= 'A';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('miss')

break;
    case 'b':
           board[i][j]= 'B';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
           touchs=touchs+1;
break;
    case 'd':
           board[i][j]= 'd';
           $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
           $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
           touchs=touchs+1;
           break;

      case 'f':
             board[i][j]= 'F';
             $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
             $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
           touchs=touchs+1;
           break;
 case 'p':
        board[i][j]= 'P';
        $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
        $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
        touchs=touchs+1;
break;
case 's':
       board[i][j]= 'S';
       $('#'+celd).removeClass('water');
       $('#'+celd).addClass('boats')
       touchs=touchs+1;
break;

  }
}
```

Shoot function invoked here:

```
function createBoardjQ(){
  $("#match").empty();
  var table = $("<table />");
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    var row = $("<tr/>");
    for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
      var celd = $('<td id="celd_'+i+'_'+j+'" onclick=shoot("celd_'+i+'_'+j+'",'+i+','+j+') > </td>');
      celd.addClass("water");
      row.append(celd);
    }
    table.append(row);
  }
  $("#match").append(table);

}
```

Callback invoked here:

```
 function createMatch(){
          //create a matrix row x col
          board = createMatrix(rows,columns);
          //fill matrix "a"
          startMatrix('a',board);
          touchs  = 0;
          setBoats(board);
          createBoardjQ();
          seconds = 15000;
          setInterval(callbackTimer, 1000);
          //ADD SECONDS TO MATCH TIMER
          //START TIMER with setInterval()
          //Overturn matrix to console
          matrix2console(board);
        }
        function callbackTimer(){
            seconds=seconds-1000;
            if(seconds===0||touchs===17){
              alert("The match has ended");

          endMatch();
          savePoints();
            }

            //if time <=0 stop clearInterval() timer and end match.

        }
```

Comment: Set a global flag and exit the second function if the flag is set.

Comment: @Pointy how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example take a look at the following snippet:

```js
var EXIT_FLAG = false;

function stopExecution()
{
  EXIT_FLAG = true;
}

var timer = setInterval(function(){
  var span = document.getElementById('timer');
  if ( EXIT_FLAG )
  { 
     clearInterval(timer);
     span.innerHTML = 'stopped!';
     return;
  }
  
  span.innerHTML = String(parseInt(span.innerHTML)+1);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="stopExecution()">Stop Execution<button>

<span id="timer">0</span>
```

Adjust snippet to fit your situation.